# How to control the position of a scollable div inside another div?

Tags: jquery, scroll, overflow

I am trying to make the scrollable inner div jump back up whet it reaches the bottom but neither .css() nor .animate() seem to work.

http://jsfiddle.net/1yzpot2b/

```js
var $fixedHolder = $('#fixedHolder'),
    $slidingHolder = $('#slidingHolder');

$fixedHolder.on('scroll', function onScroll() {
    var scrollTop = $fixedHolder.scrollTop();

    console.log('scrollTop', scrollTop);

    if (scrollTop >= 290) {
        console.info('jump up');

        $fixedHolder.off('scroll');

        $slidingHolder.css({
            top: '10px'
        });

        $slidingHolder.animate({
            scrollTop: 0
        }, 200);
    }
});
```

```css
#fixedHolder {
    width: 30px;
    height: 100px;
    overflow-y: scroll;
    border: 1px solid #ccc;
    position: relative;
}
#slidingHolder {
    position: absolute;
}
```

```html
<div id="fixedHolder">
    <div id="slidingHolder">a b c d e f g h i j k l m n o p q r s t v z x</div>
</div>
```

Comment: How do you mean "jump back up"? Do you want it to scroll back up to the topn once the user has scrolled to the bottom?

Comment: FYI you haven't included jQuery in your code snippet.

Answer (score 0):

I'm not 100% sure what you're trying to achieve but it looks like you're trying to set the `scrollTop` of the wrong element and your `scrollTop` value of `290` is way too big. You can calculate this maximum scroll height by taking the height of the `$slidingHolder` minus the `$fixedHolder` height.

See: http://jsfiddle.net/1yzpot2b/3/ or run the snippet:

```js
var $fixedHolder = $('#fixedHolder'),
    $slidingHolder = $('#slidingHolder');

$fixedHolder.on('scroll', function onScroll() {
    var scrollTop = $fixedHolder.scrollTop();

    console.log('scrollTop', scrollTop);

    var maxScroll = $slidingHolder.height() - $fixedHolder.height();
    if (scrollTop >= maxScroll) {
        console.info('jump up');
        /*
        dunno about these :
        $fixedHolder.off('scroll');

        $slidingHolder.css({
            top: '10px'
        });
        */
        $fixedHolder.animate({
            scrollTop: 0
        }, 200);
    }
});
```

```css
#fixedHolder {
    width: 30px;
    height: 100px;
    overflow-y: scroll;
    border: 1px solid #ccc;
    position: relative;
}
#slidingHolder {
    position: absolute;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.11.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<div id="fixedHolder">
    <div id="slidingHolder">a b c d e f g h i j k l m n o p q r s t v z x</div>
</div>
```